# Docker: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: docker, docker-compose, postman

I have docker running. There are no errors in the log file.

But when I try to execute a simple request via **Postman**

> POST -> http://ip:3200/api/login

I get an error:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ip:3200

What did I do wrong?

**docker ps:**

```
CONTAINER_ID  84b2968aa424     
IMAGE         top-api:latest   
COMMAND       "docker-entrypoint.s"   
PORTS         0.0.0.0:3200->3200/tcp
NAMES         top-api
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm add sharp

COPY . .

COPY ./dist ./dist

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  top.api:
    image: top-api:latest
    container_name: top-api
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 3200:3200
    volumes:
      - ./.env.dev:/app/.env.dev
```

Comment: What does `npm run start:dev` actually do?  What address and port is your application configured to listen on?  (If the service isn't listening on the special 0.0.0.0 "all addresses" interface, or if it's not on port 3200, the service will apparently start up correctly but you'll see the sort of connectivity problems you're experiencing.)

Comment: #1 if you don't have any error, enter to your container and try to connect to the service using curl. As you are already inside of the container, you could use **localhost**. For example: `curl -v http://localhost:3200/api/login`. Attach the result to your question. #2 Also share us your code or a mvp. npm run dev is not for server is for developers

Comment: See answer of @Itamar that one looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

From your host you have to connect to: `localhost:3200`. So when using postman, target `localhost:3200`.

Comment: Using **localhost:3200** the error does not change

Comment: Are you sure your application exposes to localhost:3200? Can you step into the docker container via: `docker exec -it top-api sh` and then `apk update && apk add curl && curl http://localhost:3200 -v`

Comment: @Robert-JanKuyper Can you please tell what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably listening on 127.0.0.1, which is not publicly exposed (see https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-connection-refused/ for diagrams).

Try configuring your webserver to listen on 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to expose the port 3200 by adding the following line to your Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 3200
```